# Face recognition from database using Android Vision API?

Tags: android, face-detection, vision

Hello if I capture face and then can I send the selected face to my webservice and get the person who he is ? What if I store image path in database rather than real image ? Should I check the image from folder and then send to database or what else ?

```
            Paint myRectPaint = new Paint();
            myRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            myRectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            myRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
            tempCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

            FaceDetector faceDetector = new
                    FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setTrackingEnabled(false)
                    .build();
            if(!faceDetector.isOperational()){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).setMessage("Could not set up the face detector!").show();
                return;
            }
            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
            SparseArray<Face> faces = faceDetector.detect(frame);
            for(int i=0; i<faces.size(); i++) {
                Face thisFace = faces.valueAt(i);
                float x1 = thisFace.getPosition().x;
                float y1 = thisFace.getPosition().y;
                float x2 = x1 + thisFace.getWidth();
                float y2 = y1 + thisFace.getHeight();
                tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x1, y1, x2, y2), 2, 2, myRectPaint);
            }
            myImageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),tempBitmap));
```

Here I want to send the selected face to database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Mobile Vision Text API Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254349/google-mobile-vision-text-api-example)

Comment: Yes but I want to compare the captured image with server image ?

Comment: Yes I have tried Google Vision API and can mark the landmark on face of a image. But did not find a way to match it with a image stored in server

Comment: Edit your question and Post code